# etwr/etwd Extremely High Memory Usage

Tags: windows, memory, drivers, memory-leaks, .net-core

Posted this on stackoverflow and was advised to post here for better help.

I have been using a program that I made that is built on .NET 6 and does some TCP and SQL related operations to put it simply. After purchasing some of the new HP Z series (both W11 and W10 different models) I have noticed that the program will crash and SQL will cease to work because there is no available memory. The PC's in question have 32GB and 16GB of RAM and at boot it uses ~6-7GB of RAM total. If I run the program after about 2-3 days of running the PC has entirely used up its physical RAM and starts using 30-60GB+ of paging memory. If I terminate the program it takes hours for the memory to come back to being available, it is not instant.

I have done a lot of research online into trying to narrow down where this is happening and this is what I have done and found. I used RamMap to try and see what is using the memory. I can see that for example on the 16GB PC 9.3GB is used as Nonpaged Pool, 2.8GB Paged Pool, and 2GB Process Private. I feel like the Process Private makes sense as that about adds up. However the Pool memories don't add up when I look in either the task manager details or the RamMap process tab.

In Task Manager it only shows less than 1-2MB total NP Pool usage if I sum up whats in the details tabs column and shows ~10MB in the Paged Pool column summed up. If I go to the Performance tab on Task Manager it shows 15.4GB In Use, 1.9GB Compressed,282MB Available, 62.7/63.2 Committed, 278MB Cached, 43.9GB Paged Pool, 10.1GB Nonpaged Pool, and 295MB Hardware Reserved.

After trying to figure out where these 10's of GBs of memory is going I learned about Poolmon.exe and tried to use that. I see EtwD/EtwR using 40GB of paged pool and 9GB of Nonpaged Pool respectively. I then used Tracelog -l and Logmon to try and see what aspect of Etw was using so much memory. I went down the list that was returned and didn't see anything in the buffer size or Segment Max Size that was over a few MB and did not see anything obvious to me that would explain what the issue was.

I have tried updated the BIOS/Drivers etc. to no avail either.

At this point I am at a total loss of what to try next, I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

Comment: Did you find the root cause? You can trace pool allocations with ETW. That should quickly give results.